# Android Camera GPUImage + Video

Tags: android

I wanted to shoot a video but found that there was no picture, but there were shooting documents.
I use MediaRecorder。

```
  /**
 *  
 * @param savePath
 */
public void startMediaRecord(String savePath){
    mProfile = CamcorderProfile.get(cameraFacing,CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
    if (mCamera == null || mProfile == null) return;
    mCamera.unlock();
    if (mMediaRecorder == null){
        mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(90);
    }
    if (isCameraFrontFacing()) {
        mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(270);
    }
    mMediaRecorder.reset();
    mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
    mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
    //mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(1080 * 1920);
    mMediaRecorder.setProfile(mProfile);
    //mMediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_1080P));
   // mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(20);
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(savePath);
    mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceView.getHolder().getSurface());
    //        
   // mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(width, height);
    try {
        mMediaRecorder.prepare();
        mMediaRecorder.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LogUtils.e("MYM-------->"+e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I changed part of the code，There are still questions.